# Run Sql server script to update dataBase with cmd in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am working to update sql server data base with a setup that made by Inno setup.
I write this line of command in cmd

```
sqlcmd -s myserverName -U sa  -P MyPass -d myDataBase -i scriptAddress
```

and it work correctly and i want to do same In Inno setup and Write this lines of code

```
procedure UpdateDataBase;
var
 Param:String;
 Kode : integer;
 FileName :String;
begin
 InstanceName:= DEF_INSTANCENAME;
 InstancePass:= DEF_DBPASSWORD;
 DataBaseName:= DEF_DATABASENAME;
 serverName:= 'SINA-PC\RMPRO';
 FileName:= 'C:\Update2008to2018.sql';
 Param:= ' sqlcmd -S '+ServerName+' -U sa -P '+ InstancePass+ ' -d '+ DataBaseName+ ' -i '+  
   FileName;        
  if  Exec('cmd.exe',param ,'', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated,kode) then
     begin
       showMessage('Tamam');
    end;
```

end;

but after call this procedure i have an empty cmd window. what should I do

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be calling `sqlcmd.exe` directly rather than as a parameter to `cmd.exe`.  So, you should have something like (haven't tested but should get you started):

```
pgm := 'sqlcmd.exe';
Param := '-S '+ServerName+' -U sa -P '+ InstancePass+ ' -d '+ DataBaseName+ ' -i '+ FileName;        
if  Exec(pgm, param, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, kode) then
begin
  MsgBox('Done.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: is any way to send sqlcmd as a parameter

Comment: @sina Why would you do that? What mirtheil proposes is the right way.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl in a weird situation, I cant run sqlcmd on win 7 and when using cmd with the line I wrote above everything work great and i think in this way in should work on most pc without problem

Comment: but if any good and stable way to update a database with Innosetup can help me

Comment: It would have to be `Param:= '/c sqlcmd -S ' ...` – But it does not make sense.